# Why does EF 5.0 not support this EF 4.x LINQ syntax when compiling to sql?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have some code that was recently upgraded from EF 4.2 to EF 5.0 (actually EF 4.4 since I am running on .Net 4.0). I have discovered that I had to change the syntax of my query, and I'm curious as to why. Let me start off with the problem.

I have an EventLog table that is populated by the client periodically. For each event log an entry is created in a Report table. This is the query that is run periodically to discover any event logs that do not have an entry in the Report table yet. The query I used in EF 4.2 was:

```
from el in _repository.EventLogs
where !_repository.Reports.Any(p => p.EventLogID == el.EventlogID)
```

Since upgrading to EF 5.0 I get the following error at runtime:

> System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of
>   type 'Namespace.Report'. Only primitive types or enumeration types
>   are supported in this context.

I discovered that rewriting it with the join syntax fixed the issue. The following works in EF 5.0 and is roughly the equivalent:

```
from eventLog in _repository.EventLogs
join report in _repository.Reports on eventLog.EventlogID equals report.EventLogID into alreadyReported
where !alreadyReported.Any()
```

Some people may have mixed opinions about the mixed syntax/style of the first query, but I'm really more interested in the why of this. It seems odd that the EF 4.2 compiler could generate the SQL for the original query but that the EF 5.0 refuses. Is this a setting I am missing or just a tightening of constraints between the two? Why is this happening?

Comment: Personally I think it's much more readable as a query with the join..

Comment: Could you test this instead `from el in _repository.EventLogs
where _repository.Reports.All(p => p.EventLogID != el.EventlogID)` ?

Comment: Hey King, I tried that and got the same thing. I even tried: !_repository.OntarioReports.Any(p => 5 == 5). It seems to be the mixed syntax from what I can tell.

Comment: I also noticed I had the type wrong on the error message. It is 'Namespace.Report' not 'Namespace.EventLog'.

Comment: Did upgrading require you to change anything about your models? Also, (and this is a long shot), have you overloaded the '==' operator?

Comment: No changes required for the upgrade. I have not overloaded the '==' operator, although that was a good thought. I could see automatic changes happening though under the hood. Like the way the edmx was compiled, or maybe some new default setting. I did also move the edmx to another project that is now referenced. Now that I think of it could that be part of this?

Comment: I suspect this is the same bug as described here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623498/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-of-type-user-when-using-firstordefault/18625368#18625368. The stack trace is quite similar, anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the type returned by your repository; the problem can be reproduced when `_repository.Reports` is not `IQueryable<T>`. In that case the `Reports` is considered as a non-scalar variable; which by the way is not allowed in LINQ. See [Referencing Non-Scalar Variables Not Supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx)

On your question regarding why the second query works, it is basically the following extension method of `IQueryable<T>` which group joins it with `IEnumerable<TInner>`.

```
public static IQueryable<TResult> GroupJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IQueryable<TOuter> outer,IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
    Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>> outerKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector,
    Expression<Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>, TResult>> resultSelector)
```

Which just accepts the expression for the key selectors for both outer and inner(instead of referencing non scalar variables); in which the above constraint doesn't apply.

**Note:** If `_repository.Reports` is of `IQueryable<T>` the first query will work; because EF will build the expression tree correctly and execute the appropriate SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Just for curiosities sake, have you tried converting

```
from el in _repository.EventLogs
where !_repository.Reports.Any(p => p.EventLogID == el.EventlogID)
```

to

```
from el in _repository.EventLogs
where !_repository.Reports.Where(p => p.EventLogID == el.EventlogID).Any();
```

or

```
from el in _repository.EventLogs
where !_repository.Reports.Where(p => p.EventLogID == el.EventlogID).Count() > 0;
```

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: These all produce the same behavior.