# Unable to create a constant value of type X

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq-to-entities

I'm having a problem with a Linq-To-Entities query, about deferred execution, which I'm trying to understand. Here's the code:

```cs
public QuestaoSimulado GetByID(int idQuestao)
{
    var query = (from questao in ctx.tblQuestoes
                    where questao.intQuestaoID == idQuestao
                    select new QuestaoSimulado()
                    {
                        Enunciado = questao.txtEnunciado,
                        Comentario = questao.txtComentario,
                        Id = questao.intQuestaoID,
                        Ano = questao.intYear ?? 0,
                        Tipo = questao.bitCasoClinico == "1" ? (int)Questao.tipoQuestao.DISCURSIVA : (int)Questao.tipoQuestao.OBJETIVA,
                        Video = ctx.tblVideo_Questao_Simulado.Any(v => v.intQuestaoID == questao.intQuestaoID)
                }).FirstOrDefault();
    return query;
}
```

This specific query triggers this exception :

> the NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of
>   type "tblVideo_Questao_Simulado". Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in
>   this context.

And I understand that it happens because the `Any()` method in the subquery is not deferred executed, and executes instantly in the database (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Now, the problem: This query doesn't work on my machine because of this, but the same code works on the machine of a coworker. Also, it doesn't work on our Testing environment, but it works on Production. I'm trying to find information to understand why it works on one environment and not the other. Maybe this happens because the version of the framework is different or something else (I'm using .Net Framework 4.7.1), but I still didn't manage to find anything useful to understand this scenario

Any light about this situation is truly appreciated.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Testing in our environments, the difference is that the dll that works is being built with Visual Studio 2012, but the same code throws this exception in Visual Studio 2017. I'm searching for information about differences in compilation from both versions. If anyone has any insights, it would be great!

Comment: It's not related to the 'non-deferred' execution itself. It's something else and I suggest you finish the sentence `Unable to create a constant value of type...` with the actual type that is in error.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the question with the type

Comment: Are you using EF Core or EF 6?

Comment: @NetMage EF 4.4.0.0

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19133102/2557128) seems like it might pertain: what is the type of `tblVideo_Questao_Simulado`?

Comment: @NetMage this post you've shared makes sense, but still doesn't explain why its working on my coworker machine with VS2012, and the same code (with same version of EF) doesn't work on my VS2017. Also, the class is a DbSet of my EDMX model for Entity Framework: DbSet<tblVideo_Questao_Simulado> tblVideo_Questao_Simulado { get; set; }

Comment: Apparently it depends on the data provider - what version of .Net is targeted by VS2012 vs vs2017?

Comment: The target framework on both VS's is .NET Framework 4

Comment: Have you already tried setting the C# Language Level on your project to the same one as VS2012?  I think VS2012 uses C#5.0 and the default for VS2017 is C# 7.0; Perhaps if they're both the same you'd get the same results.

Comment: Didn't think about that, I'll give it a try. Thank you @Andrew